# Inductive proof about Jensen's inequality

Tags: real-analysis, induction

> **Problem 6** (Jensen's inequality). Let $f: I \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a concave up function, $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ an interval, and $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n \in (0, \infty)$ positive real numbers with $\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k = 1$. Show that for all $x_1, \dots, x_n \in I$,
>
> $$f(\lambda_1x_1 + \dots + \lambda_nx_n) \leq \lambda_1f(x_1) + \dots + \lambda_nf(x_n)\textrm{.}$$
>
> If $f$ is strict concave up then equality in the above can only occur if $x_1 = x_2 = \dots = x_n$.
>
> *Hint*: induction on $n$. For the induction step $n \to n+1$ set $\lambda := \lambda_1 + \dots + \lambda_n$ and $x := \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda} x_1 + \dots + \frac{\lambda_n}{\lambda}x_n$.

The base case is easy.

For the inductive step, i take $\lambda$ and $x$ to be as given, and then when I consider

$f(\lambda_1 x_1 + . . . + \lambda_n x_n + \lambda_{n+1} x_{n+1})$

I get this is

$f(\lambda(x) + \lambda_{n+1} x_{n+1})$

I feel like I'm quite close but I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: From there, use the fact that by the base case, i.e. Jensen holds for two variables, expand, and use Jensen for $n$ variables.

Comment: My base case was just $n=1$. So since we required the sum of all the lambda to be 1, we just had $\lambda_1 = 1$ so $f(\lambda_1 x_1) = f(x_1) = \lambda_1 f(x_1)$. Was this a bad choice for the base case? I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: Ok, then you will need to show for $n=2$. Depending on how you have defined "concave up" property, this may be quite trivial.

Comment: @Macavity I have that a concave up function is below the secant lines between any two points for the entire region it is concave up on. (is there a good, rigorous way to define this using notation?)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the inequality for $n=2$. $((1-t)x_1+tx_2,(1-t)f(x-1)+tf(x_2))$ is the secant line segment for $t\in[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you all so much! I completed the proof.